# adding a SpriteKit particle to existing app

Tags: ios, ipad

Ive added a SpriteKit particle to my app - The skView has been added to an existing image view (myImageView). All works well but the skScenne cannot be set to clear colour to show myImage behind the emitter. You can change the colour but not to clear colour ??  `

```
    SKView *skView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 768, 1024)];

[myImageView addSubview:skView];

SKScene *skScene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:skView.frame.size];
skScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
skScene.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


SKEmitterNode *emitter =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle          mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyParticle" ofType:@"sks"]];
```

emitter.position = CGPointMake(400,0);

```
[skScene addChild:emitter];
[skView presentScene:skScene];


[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't make an SKView transparent in iOS 7. In iOS 8 it works by using:

```
skView.allowsTransparency = YES;
skScene.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

In iOS 7 you can add a large spriteView that is as big as your skView as background and set your myImage as texture.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you avoid setting the color of your SKScene to [UIColor clearColor] for performance reasons (use opaque views whenever possible). Instead, you can create an SKSpriteNode and add it to your scene as the background...

```
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"image"];

background.size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
// Bottom/left of your image
background.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
background.position = CGPointZero;
// Make sure the background is behind other nodes in the scene
background.zPosition = -100;

[self addChild:background];
```

Since the background is added to the SKScene, it is automatically removed/released when you transition to a new scene.